tlmgr complaining/installing about packages on other platforms
I am on Manjaro Linux and recently had a kernel issue. I have solved it, but my TeX Live distribution is now broken. I don't know if the kernel issue is related to that. Whenever I run sudo tlmgr update --self --all, I get messages of the following sort.
tlmgr: package repository https://mirror.niser.ac.in/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/share/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available
tlmgr: skipping forcibly removed package: asmejour
/usr/bin/tlmgr: (make_container autosp.i386-solaris.r69782.tar) bin/i386-solaris/autosp does not exist
/usr/bin/tlmgr: (make_container autosp.i386-solaris.r69782.tar) bin/i386-solaris/tex2aspc does not exist
[  1/783, ??:??/??:??] update: autosp.i386-solaris [20k] (69782 -> 71441) ... done
/usr/bin/tlmgr: (make_container autosp.x86_64-darwinlegacy.r69782.tar) bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy/autosp does not exist
/usr/bin/tlmgr: (make_container autosp.x86_64-darwinlegacy.r69782.tar) bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy/tex2aspc does not exist
[  2/783, 00:02/43:56:45] update: autosp.x86_64-darwinlegacy [20k] (69782 -> 71441) ... done
/usr/bin/tlmgr: (make_container autosp.x86_64-linuxmusl.r69784.tar) bin/x86_64-linuxmusl/autosp does not exist
/usr/bin/tlmgr: (make_container autosp.x86_64-linuxmusl.r69784.tar) bin/x86_64-linuxmusl/tex2aspc does not exist
[  3/783, 00:03/33:20:50] update: autosp.x86_64-linuxmusl [21k] (69784 -> 71441) ... done
/usr/bin/tlmgr: (make_container autosp.x86_64-solaris.r69782.tar) bin/x86_64-solaris/autosp does not exist
/usr/bin/tlmgr: (make_container autosp.x86_64-solaris.r69782.tar) bin/x86_64-solaris/tex2aspc does not exist
[  4/783, 00:04/29:25:19] update: autosp.x86_64-solaris [22k] (69782 -> 71441) ... done
/usr/bin/tlmgr: (make_container avremu.r35373.tar) texmf-dist/doc/latex/avremu/README does not exist

I did sudo tlmgr platform set x86_64-linux as well, but this does not help as well.

you shouldn't use tlmgr to update if you installed tex with pacman. you should update with pacman as part of a systemwide update i.e. pacman -Syu. (or whatever wrapper manjaro uses for pacman.) if you want to manage the installation with tlmgr, install vanilla texlive from upstream and a dummy package for pacman.

@cfr I installed vanilla TeX Live with the installer provided from the TeX Live website, not using pacman. tlmgr was working fine a few days ago.

then either you changed the installation root to a system directory (which is a very bad idea) or you have two texlives installed: one vanilla and one from manjaro. by default, vanilla texlive does not touch anything under /usr/share. the only thing it touches (if you agree) is /usr/bin to install symbolic links. (I don't let it do this, but it can do it.) the output you posted clearly shows tlmgr is using /usr/share and not /usr/local. if you didn't install a dummy package and didn't pay attention to what pacman installed, you probably didn't notice it install another one.

you can manage things so the installations coexist peacefully. or you can remove your distro's packages and install a dummy package so pacman thinks texlive is installed. personally, I prefer the latter approach because I don't have to worry about which is the 'right' tlmgr, pdftex etc. so I install a dummy package to satisfy pacman, which means I can install things which depend on texlive without pacman installing texlive. but that's my preference and a personal choice.

@cfr Yes, you are right!! texlive was a dependency for kile and it inadvertentely installed it. I used to manually change the config file so that pacman does not install the programs from the repository, but i forgot this time. Now i unistalled the pacman installed packages and tlmgr does not work at all. I get the error that tlmgr not found.

My path echo $PATH shows /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/apoorvpotnis/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

that's why you need to install a dummy package ;). (also, it means you don't have to build things available in binary form like kile unless you want to.) do you have /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr? it should be a symbolic link.

@cfr I don't have tlmgr in /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/. Can you please share the link for the dummy package? I am on Manjaro and searched for texlive-dummy, or just dummy but I couldn't see any packages available. Thanks.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is the PKGBUILD I use to build a dummy package. Note that this is tested for Arch Linux and not Manjaro. For Manjaro, you should check the names of the texlive packages are correct.
pkgname=texlive-dummy-cfr
pkgver=2.0
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="TeX typesetting program"
arch=(i686 x86_64)
license=('custom')
provides=('tetex' 'texlive-bin' 'texlive-core' 'texinfo' 'texlive-basic')
conflicts=('tetex' 'texlive-bin' 'texlive-core' 'texlive-basic')
build() {
/bin/true
}
package() {
/bin/true
}

